# Adding Custom Menu in Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, configuration, backend, menu

To create a **custom menu in back-end** we create **`adminhtml.xml`** with following code into this file. My question is which file(s) are responsible to process this **`adminhtml.xml`** file to add our new menu item to the menu.

```
<adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <[module] module="[module]">
                <title>[Module]</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>               
                <children>
                    <items module="[module]">
                        <title>Manage Items</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>[module]/adminhtml_[module]</action>
                    </items>
                </children>
            </[module]>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <[module]>
                            <title>[Module] Module</title>
                            <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                        </[module]>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>   
        </acl>
</adminhtml>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to `app/design/adminhtml/layout/main.xml` this block is loaded for the menu:

```
<block type="adminhtml/page_menu" name="menu" as="menu"></block>
```

So that concludes that `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Page_Menu` (`function _buildMenuArray`) takes care of building the menu and processing everything. Of course many different components are used in this block.

Comment: Worth noting that this block ooutput is cached in the `block_html` cache.